# Error Deploying Next.js App with mongoDb to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, next.js

I've been trying to deploy my Next.js application with mongoDb to heroku platform with no luck. it builds successfully without any errors but for some reasons my app does not work. I checked my heroku logs, and i found this error message

```
2020-08-17T21:09:10.846691+00:00 app[web.1]: FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/notes/favicon.ico failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

I researched a lot about this issue but i haven't been able to come up with a solution. Here's where i'm making a connection to my mongoDb. i have also added my config Vars in the heroku GUI

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const connection = {}

const dbConnect = async () => {
if (connection.isConnected) {
  return
} 
 const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
   dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
   user: process.env.DB_USER,
   pass: process.env.DB_PASS,
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
 })

 connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState
 console.log(connection.isConnected, 'Db connected')
}

export default dbConnect
```

Comment: You need to elaborate further on "my app does not work."

Comment: Hi! The homepage gets displayed and i can navigate to different routes. but the data that is supposed to be coming from mongoDb is not being displayed. i cannot perform any CRUD operation

Comment: there could be a multitude of reasons. you need to test and isolate each step to log along with the way - you cannot simply post a question saying my website doesn't work. not trying to be harsh, but it is impossible to try and track down the issue for you. sounds like you have connection issues - start there